# vector pointer causing valgrind memory leak

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm trying to learn C++ and valgrind. So I wrote the following code to test it out. But I get some memory leaks. Can anyone explain what's causing the memory leak? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
     int c;
      public:
      void whatever();
}; 
void test:: whatever()
{
     vector<test*> a;
     if(true)
     {
           test* b = new test();
           b->c = 1;
           a.push_back(b);
     }
     test* d = a.back();
     cout << "prints: " << d->c;
     delete d;
}

int main()
{
    test* a = new test();
    a->whatever();
    return 1;
}
```

from valgrind

```
==28548== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28548==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==28548==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 16 bytes allocated
==28548==
==28548== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==28548==    at 0x4C27CC1: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==28548==    by 0x400C36: main (in a.out)
==28548==
==28548== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28548==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==28548==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28548==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28548==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28548==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28548==
==28548== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28548== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Am I not allowed to delete from a copy of a pointer or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You never call `delete` on `a`.

Of course, the important bit here is that you are using a `vector` of pointers.  Why in the world would you do this?  Let the vector take care of memory management for you!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `delete a;` at the end of `main()`.

Note that everything you wrote should *never* go into real code. You should never use dynamic allocation (`new`) unless you absolutely have to and know precisely why.

---

Assuming you want to maintain the vector of pointers for educational purposes, then here's a better way of writing it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>  // for unique_ptr

// intentionally left blank; NO abusing namespace std!

struct Foo
{
    int c;

    void whatever()
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test>> v;

        if (true)
        {
            v.emplace_back(new test);
            v.back()->c = 1;
        }

        // everything is cleaned up automagically
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test a;        // automatic, not dynamic
    a.whatever();

    return 1;
}
```

This is still just for educational purposes; in real life you would try very hard to make do with a plain `std::vector<test>`, since `vector` is *already* a dynamic data structure and there is little need for the extra level of indirection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really helpful for a beginner like me. But what happens if you need to pass pointers around due to an external function? Would it be okay to use a vector/array of pointers or is there a better solution you'd recommend?

Comment: @oliten: You can use the address-of operator `&` :-)

Comment: @oliten: `some_func(&vec[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak is in main. You are not deleting the allocated `test` object.